# How to build the graph of this text?

Tags: graphs

I am with the following question, because I do not know if what the following paragraph indicates:

[image]

Does this refer to this image?

[image]

Maybe to this other?

[image]

If not, tell me what you are referring to please. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's the second one.
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/06au/projects/modeler/heightfield.html

Comment: You should ask the setter of the question.

Comment: I think neither. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph => To be k-connected, each vertex should have at least k edges (which is trivially a necessary condition but not generally sufficient on its own -- ie, consider multiple edges or self-loops in a general graph). Your first graph (red, above) is 2-connected, and your second (black, below) is 3-connected.

Comment: The second one is 8-connected in Computer Graphics with boundary condition, meaning algorithms like flood fill use special case for hull, but the grid is not 8-connected as graph, because corners have 3 connections and the rest of the hull 5. Since there is a graph-theory tag, none is the answer.